# Images I pull from a database sometimes don't show in the browser, but they do if I view the source

Tags: php, mysql, image

I've started developing a site that pulls two images randomly from a database.

I assign a random number to a variable, between 1 and the amount of images there are stored in my database.  I then query the database looking for that ID, and show the image in HTML image tags.  This works fine and the two images appear randomly and I have checking to make sure they are never the same.  But sometimes, one or both of the images won't appear on the page but if I view the source code, they are appearing there.

( I should note that the images aren't actually stored WITHIN the database, just the names of them are )

Here is the code that I am using to withdraw them from the database

```
function selectImage($id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Images WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
        $image = $row['image'];
        echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
    }
}
```

Anyone know why this only displays the image sometimes?  I'm refreshing to make it display another set of images.

Comment: a better approach would be to  use *order by rand* and *LIMIT 2* in the query

Comment: Thankyou, I was not aware that you could order by rand.  That does seem a lot easier. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it can be tricky to sync up the filesystem with the database: If you are able to view the src in the HTML, and the image doesn't appear, then chances are the image doesn't exist, the name is stored incorrectly in your database, or perhaps the extension is being saved incorrectly *(storing .jpg but the file is .jpeg or .JPG)*.

Comment: I can see it in the source, and when I click on the link in the source (using firefox) it actually takes me to the image.  So I doubt it is that.

Comment: Have you disabled styles to make sure it is not a CSS issue? Tried outputting all images at once, to make sure they all appear? Made sure you are not breaking your html with illegal attribute values (alt, title, etc.)?

Comment: Ahah, I've solved it!  One of the images apparently 'has errors'.  Not sure how that is but I've re-upped it and it works fine.